# Google Sheets: Multiple "if" and "find" within an Array formula

Tags: if-statement, text, google-sheets, find, array-formulas

***background info - not important***

I realise I need improvement on understanding logic and understanding documentation when playing around with Android apps. So, I thought I'll switch to Google Sheets in the hope of some basic practice in a context I might find easier to understand.

***question***

I've set up a Google Sheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1T7q_CGMFObxS_0DGikUdSdLTf97XmEPXY0S7yItuA5Y/edit?usp=sharing

I would like Column B to:

- display "Folder1" if "Black" is found in the adjacent Column A cell.
- display "Folder2" if "Blue" is found in the adjacent Column A cell.
- display "Folder3" if "Green" is found in the adjacent Column A cell.

and to then be able to add more conditions.

My formula for Column B is currently:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
 IFS(
    find("Black", A2:A,1)>0,"Folder1",
    find("Blue", A2:A,1)>0,"Folder2",
    find("Green", A2:A,1)>0,"Folder3")
 )
```

Which is only meeting the first condition `"Folder1"` if `"Black"` is found and not continuing with the rest of the `if` clauses.

I think I have nested it correctly though because all of the `IFS()` are at the same level with their corresponding `find()` within. And, I have two closing brackets which close the `IFS` and the `ARRAYFORMULA`.

Am I just simply not using the right kind of functions for what I'd like to do?

Thank you for your suggestions on how I can solve this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `find()` only returns a number `> 0` if it actually finds a match. Otherwise it returns an error which you can't test for explicitly.

You can fix you code like this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
 IFS(
 isnumber(find("Black", A2:A,1)),"Folder1",
 isnumber(find("Blue", A2:A,1)),"Folder2",
 isnumber(find("Green", A2:A,1)),"Folder3")
 )
```

Now we can test that what `find()` returns is an number and the code will work!
Obviously, I put on multiple lines for clarity.

Comment: Let me know it this works ... I tested on your sheet.

Comment: Thank you very much, I don't know how I would have come across that! I've also found that "search" instead of "find" will search irrespective of case.

Comment: Yes it quite bad that its not properly documented how to deal the `error` return values. To be honest I did a search for examples and I found a `search()` example that used the `isnumber()` function, and it worked for `find()` also. With experience you learn to find workarounds!